# Specify tile size for Blender Cycles rendering via the command line

Tags: python, scripting, command-line

I'd like to write a little piece of code which splits a frame into a few tiles and uses all available devices to render the still image. It seems like the Blender developers are working on such a feature, but this seems to be quite far in the future: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/Devices.

Because I render images which are composited into photographs (resolution about 5300 x 3800) I want to use all the resources I have available (CPU & GPU in main workstation, CPU in laptop and CPU in old desktop).
I have found the documentation for the command line (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Command_Line), but it doesn't specify the options I need (tile mode, tile size x and y, number of tiles to render).

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3061/setting-render-options-from-the-command-line

Comment: Related to networked rendering: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/906/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/is-netrender-only-useful-for-multiple-frames

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK, there is no option to set tile sizes directly from the command line.

However, you could use the [python api](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_5/contents.html) to do this, and execute a python script in blender from the command line. (see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui))

To set tile sizes from python, you can use
[`bpy.context.scene.render.tile_x`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_5/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html?highlight=tile#bpy.types.RenderSettings.tile_x)
and [`bpy.context.scene.render.tile_y`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_5/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html?highlight=tile#bpy.types.RenderSettings.tile_y).

Tile order can be set with `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].cycles.tile_order`.
This can be set to `'CENTER', 'RIGHT_TO_LEFT', 'LEFT_TO_RIGHT', 'TOP_TO_BOTTOM',` or `'BOTTOM_TO_TOP'`

An example script to set the tile size to 32x32 and set the order to `Right to Left`:

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    scene.render.tile_x = 32
    scene.render.tile_y = 32
    scene.cycles.tile_order = 'RIGHT_TO_LEFT'
```

Note that it loops through each scene to set these properties globally. (see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3062/599))
You can run this from the command line with

```
blender --background /path/to/my.blend --python /path/to/script.py --render-anim
# or the short version:
blender -b /path/to/my.blend -P /path/to/script.py -a
```

## Borders:

AFAIK, it's not possible to tell blender to only render n amount of tiles, when n is less than the total tiles needed to render the complete image.
(blender does print a new line to stdout for every tile that is rendered, so you might be able to make some hack to stop blender once n tiles have been rendered, but I don't know if you could save output.)

Because of this, you might be better off using the [*Render Border*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Output#Dimensions); this will allow you to exactly define what section of the image to render.
You could then call blender to render repeatedly, using a script to pass different render border dimensions to do your own "tile render".

You can enable border with `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.use_border = True`

The border region is defined by four values between `0` and `1` corresponding to the locations of the four sides of the render border relative to the camera where `0` is the left or bottom edge of the camera, and `1` is the right or top edge.

You can set the [min and max xy values for the *camera* border](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_5/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html?highlight=border_max_x#bpy.types.RenderSettings.border_max_x) with

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.border_max_x
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.border_min_x
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.border_max_y
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.border_min_y
```

You may also want to enable *Crop to border* with `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.use_crop_to_border = True`

So to render half of the image vertically, you could run this:

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:

    scene.render.use_border = True
    scene.render.use_crop_to_border = True
    #this sets the render border to the left half of the camera. 
    #to render the right half, set max_x to 1 and min_x to .5
    scene.render.border_max_x = .5
    scene.render.border_min_x = 0
    scene.render.border_min_y = 0
    scene.render.border_max_y = 1
    scene.render.tile_x = 32
    scene.render.tile_y = 32
#then render:
bpy.ops.render.render()
```

Note that to set the *viewport* border you must use [this](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_5/bpy.ops.view3d.html?highlight=border#bpy.ops.view3d.render_border) instead, but you most likely are interested in camera border as viewport border is only relevant for using the realtime rendering feature. (see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2023/599) for more info)

## Seeds:

This does not answer your question about tiles, but as you mentioned you want to do this for rendering on multiple machines, I thought I would mention this.

You could also combine different Cycles renders by using the [Seed](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Integrator#Scene_Settings) value. (See [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/998/599) for more info)

This also is a good way to remove [fireflies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/what-is-the-reason-cycles-creates-incorrectly-colored-firefly-artifact-pixels).

Comment: I can't get
scene.render.tile_x = 32
to work with Blender 2.79 - does anybody know if the naming and/or functionality changed?

Comment: @A.Tropics Works for me, any error message? Also, you don't have the *auto tile size* addon enabled by any chance, do you?

Comment: _auto tile size_ is disabled, no error message. The crazy thing is, my script did work with 2.77, but doesn't any more. One thing I thought about: My code is added to bpy.app.handlers.render_pre, so it gets called before rendering. When I run the script manually, the tiles setting in the GUI changes. Maybe the code _does_ work, but the tile size gets overwritten again afterwards? Is there any way I can test for this? I would look in the source code but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Remember that there are two things that refer to tile size: render only a portion of the screen that you define and the internal slice that the cycles engine uses to render the frame in pieces (tile size from the render engine). Note: This will become invalid with Blender 3.0 which does not use tiles to render, but renders the whole frame, the addon autotile_size will become obsolete with that release.