# Changing tile location

Tags: cycles-render-engine, python

I want to be able to render a tile and then move to the left and render that tile

[Specify tile size for Blender Cycles rendering via command line](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/specify-tile-size-for-blender-cycles-rendering-via-command-line)

So far I have gotten this... I have no idea how to make it loop to the next one. I'm new to this.

It runs without error but I'm sure its all wrong:

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    mx = scene.render.border_max_x = 0
    sx = scene.render.border_min_x = 0
    sy = scene.render.border_min_y = 0
    my = scene.render.border_max_y = 0
    scene.render.use_border = True
    scene.render.use_crop_to_border = True
if 1 > 0:
    my = my + .2;
    mx = mx + .2;
    scene.render.border_max_x = mx
    scene.render.border_min_x = 0
    scene.render.border_min_y = 0
    scene.render.border_max_y = my
    int (my);
    int (mx);

    bpy.ops.render.render()
```

Comment: my math isnt done yet so dont make fun lololol

Comment: What is `if 1 > 0` for?

Comment: I'm quite sure why you assigned `mx` `sx` etc. to `scene.render.border_min/max_x/y = 0`, then assigned `scene.render.border_min/max_x/y` to `mx`, `sx` etc.?

Do you want `mx = 0`, then `scene.render.border_max_x = mx`?

Comment: And you are making a loop in initialization and after it you do an if that is always done (1 is greater than 0 all time). Take in mind that if you want to make the if statement executed in each scene you must tab in it (tabs are important in python).

Comment: Could you use a [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop? If I understand what you want, couldn't you use a `while loop` instead of `if 1 > 0:`? This would repeat the render and increment `mx` and `my` until the statement after the `while` is false.

Comment: i am really new to python so it may look weird to people who know how to use it. i was just trying to get it to loop and after i can i will work out the amount of times i should loop it.
_____________________
so gandalf3 i have no idea what im doing. thats why haha.
----------------------
and PhoneixS yes i know :3 its just for getting the loop to work and seeing how it behaves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`if` statement](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) does not cause the code following it to loop, it merely executes the code indented after the `if` only if the statement following the `if` (in this case `1 > 0`) is true.

## While loop:

If I understand what you are trying to do, you want a [`while` statement](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) instead of an `if` statement:

```
var = 0 # define the variable "var"
while 10 > var: # while 10 is greater than whatever value "var" is equal too
    var = var + 1 # increment var by one
    print (var) # print var to the console
```

This will execute the code indented after `while 10 > var:` until `var` is no longer less than `10`.

The result of running the above code is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

So if we apply this to your code:

```
import bpy

var = 0 # assign these variables to 0
mx = 0 # I removed these from the scene for loop because you don't need to set them again for eaach scene.
sx = 0
sy = 0
my = 0
for scene in bpy.data.scenes: # loop through each scene in the .blend and set these values in each one:
    scene.render.use_border = True # enable borders
    scene.render.use_crop_to_border = True # enable crop to border

while var < 3: # as long as "var" is equal to a number less than 3, execute:
    var = var + 1 # increase "var" by one (very important if we don't want to run the loop for infinity)
    my = my + .2 
    mx = mx + .2
    scene.render.border_max_x = mx
    scene.render.border_min_x = 0
    scene.render.border_min_y = 0
    scene.render.border_max_y = my
    #                                                          vv var is an INT, so we convert it to a string for the perposes of using it in the output image file name
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/tmp/test_render_" + str(var) + ".png" # bpy.context.scene gives us the currently open scene, so we can set the path for outputting images for only that scene.
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) # I added the write_still=True so the render is writted to the file spcified in scene.render.filepath
```

## Explanation:

Here is an explanation of what each line does:

---

`import bpy` This [imports](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/import.html) the [`bpy`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Introduction#The_bpy_Module) [module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html).

---

`var = 0` This assigns "var" to a value, `0`. See the [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings#Variables) for more about variables.

---

`for scene in bpy.data.scenes:` This is a [`for statement`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) that will repeat the code indented after this line for each [scene](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=scenes) in [`bpy.data.scenes`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.BlendData.html?highlight=scenes#bpy.types.BlendData.scenes). (this will also assign `scene` as a kind of variable containing the location of the current scene being iterated through.)

---

`scene.render.use_border = True` This sets blender's variable [`use_border`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html?highlight=use_border#bpy.types.RenderSettings.use_border) to `True`. This is the same as ticking the check box in the GUI (*Render settings > Dimensions*):

[image]

To illustrate this, you can run `bpy.context.scene.render.use_border = True` in the [Python console](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Console) and the *Border* check box will become enabled in the GUI.

---

`scene.render.use_crop_to_border = True` This enables *Crop to border* (`[use_crop_to_border][13]`)

---

`while var < 3:` Test if `var` is equal to a value less than `3`. If true, then execute the indented code following this line and test if `var < 3` again. If false, skip to the next unindented code.

---

`var = var + 1` Assign `var` to the result of `var + 1` (increment by one)

---

`scene.render.border_max_x = mx` Set blender's variable [`border_max_x`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html?highlight=border_max_x#bpy.types.RenderSettings.border_max_x) to the current value of the variable `mx`.

---

`bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/tmp/test_render_" + str(var) + ".png"` Use [`bpy.context`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.context.html?highlight=bpy.context#bpy.context) to get the [active scene](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.context.html?highlight=bpy.context#bpy.context.scene) and set the [scene render property](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.render) [`filepath`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings.filepath) to a string. to use the variable `var` (type `INT`) in the string, it needs to be converted to a string type with `str(var)`. See the [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings#Combining_Numbers_and_Strings) for more info about strings and variables.

---

[`bpy.ops.render.render`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.render.html?#bpy.ops.render.render)`(write_still=True)` This renders the image and writes it to the path specified in [`filepath`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings.filepath).

---

## Result:

The above code outputs the following images in `/tmp/` when run in the *Text editor*:

`test_render_1.png` is created with the border settings set to these values:

```
scene.render.border_max_x = .2
scene.render.border_min_x = 0
scene.render.border_min_y = 0
scene.render.border_max_y = .2
```

[image: test_render_1.png]

---

`test_render_2.png` is created with the border settings set to these values:

```
scene.render.border_max_x = .4
scene.render.border_min_x = 0
scene.render.border_min_y = 0
scene.render.border_max_y = .4
```

[image: test_render_2.png]

---

`test_render_3.png` is created with the border settings set to these values:

```
scene.render.border_max_x = .6
scene.render.border_min_x = 0
scene.render.border_min_y = 0
scene.render.border_max_y = .6
```

[image: test_render_3.png]

The total number of images is limited to `3` because the third time the loop code is executed, the variable `var` is incremented to `3` which is not less than `3`.

Here is a code that moves to the next "tile" over:

```
import bpy

var = 0 
mx = 0 
sx = -.2
sy = 0
my = .2
for scene in bpy.data.scenes: 
    scene.render.use_border = True 
    scene.render.use_crop_to_border = True

while var < 3:
    var = var + 1
    mx = mx + .2
    sx = sx + .2
    print (mx)
    print (sx)
    scene.render.border_max_x = mx
    scene.render.border_min_x = sx
    scene.render.border_min_y = sy
    scene.render.border_max_y = my

    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = "/tmp/test_render_" + str(var) + ".png"
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Comment: @gandalf3 Completely off topic, but you made [two](http://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/3571/3) separate [edits](http://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/3571/4) that both added exactly 1426 characters to the post... this is either ridiculous coincidence or you have way too much time on your hands.

Comment: @WChargin 0.o That's pretty incredible (And I certainly didn't plan it)

Comment: gandalf is a wizard!

Comment: upvote for just the extent of explaining a simple problem that could have been fixed by watching a beginner python tutorial on youtube.