# How to render a portion of the image through command line with background image

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

My question is related to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/specify-tile-size-for-blender-cycles-rendering-via-command-line), in fact I use a compositing node to add a background image to the scene and it stays centered in each rendered image, what I don't want.

This is the py code I'm using;

```
scene.render.use_border = True
scene.render.use_crop_to_border = True
scene.render.border_max_x = .5
scene.render.border_min_x = 0
scene.render.border_min_y = 0
scene.render.border_max_y = 1
scene.render.tile_x = 32
scene.render.tile_y = 32
```

Maybe I can add a similar code for the background image but I don't know enough blender python api.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped searching, I created a plane with the background image as a texture and make the camera as parent, I put it far with an emissive shader node and far enough not to emit on my scene object, in another render layer.

This way instead of an texture layer and a render layer, I have two render layers subject to the scene.render.border.