# How to set up a render farm

Tags: rendering, linux

I got my hands on three identical PC towers, I would like to hook them up into a render farm, but I would like some advice on what opperating system I should use. I know that I need one of them to be a master, when I looked up linux I found that they had a linux server, is that the sort of thing I'd want for the master?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOjQET1hAEQ

Comment: Also see https://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/08/09/setting-up-a-render-farm/ and https://youtu.be/_Oqo383uviw

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/906/set-up-a-render-farm-with-multiple-os-and-spec

Comment: This seems like more of a general question to me, a canonical answer would be nice tho.

Answer (score 10):

To setup a render farm you need multiple computers that can talk to each other over a network. Then you setup one as a master and the others as slaves that will get their workload from the master.

Blender includes a network render addon that just needs to be enabled in preferences then configured on each machine.

[Flamenco](http://flamenco.io/) is the new network render project being worked on.

For a small farm you can also manually start blender on each machine, giving each a different range of frames to render. With *nix machines this can be done through an ssh connection with `blender -b myscene.blend -s 1 -e 10 -a`, this can be expanded to a script that can automate sending the command to each machine for you.

Comment: thank you, this info will help me later on, but what I need to know now is what is the best operating system to use. I've heard a lot of people use linux, but I have never used linux before, so I don't know anything about it.

Comment: The best system to use is the one you are comfortable using, or can easily find help in learning. Also the cost of windows can make *nix more desirable. A *nix machine is usually easier to run remotely using a cli, while with windows you can use vnc or rdc to control the machine remotely.

Comment: Thank you again, I think I'll try Linux, I have enough copies of Windows to fall back on. You have been very helpful.

Comment: @sambler I would like to have a look at Flamenco but when I read the Readme at https://github.com/armadillica/flamenco I don't understand how to install this software. Do you have any experience with Flamenco ?

Comment: No I haven't setup flamenco yet. The readme lists commands to install pre-built [docker setups](https://www.docker.com/products/overview), which is like a virtual disk image with everything setup. You could try `#flamenco` on IRC, which is quite so it may be a while till someone else is there to respond. Farms like [render.st](http://render.st) or [lionrender.com](http://lionrender.com) lessen the need to setup your own.

Comment: We've considerably improved the documentation in the past weeks, it's worth checking out https://flamenco.io/ again.