# Send blender simulation to another computer for processing and caching?

Tags: python, rendering, network

I have two computers, one I use for working and the other I want to use for rendering and doing any other task that require lots of CPU usage. I have a decent knowledge in Python and the Blender API, but I've never done any kind of networking. There is also a big lack of information online regarding distributed rendering with Blender 2.8.

The easiest way to calculate a simulation on another computer would be to write a small addon that would send my current .blend to the 'slave' computer and automatically start the calculation/render. Fortunately this is quite simpler than a render farm with multiple computers which would require some load sharing but still I'm not sure where to start exactly.
I think the .blend sharing will be easy but then I'm not certain how I'll start Blender on the other machine from my main PC and start the simulation/rendering process without having to manually do anything.

This should work online as well, if I'm abroad I'd love to be able to harness the power of my slave PC at home from my laptop.

I guess it's more of a broad question on how this things are approached by people who know what they are doing!

Relevant post: [How can I run blender from command line or a python script without opening a GUI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30765/15543

Comment: I don't want to use Flamenco because it's paid (blender cloud sub), and the network addon is gone in 2.8. CrowdRender looks like a decent alternative but it only handle rendering, not simulations as far as I know.