# Blender rendering server, local

Tags: rendering

I am wondering if there is a way to setup a local server to render blends on my network.

Work on a model on client, press a button through some add-on, send that file to the server for rendering. Is there anything like this?

Comment: The term is called `render farm`. These have some more info - http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/906/935 http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30755/935